# Check whether an attribute is customer attribute or customer address attribute

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I have the following code where I need to check whether the attribute in question is a customer attribute or customer address attribute. How do I check that?

`private $custom_columns = array();`

```
public function __construct() 
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('customerGrid');
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
    $this->setDefaultSort('email');
    $this->setDefaultLimit('200');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    $attributeIds = Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionname/group/field');
    $this->custom_columns = array($attributeIds); 
}
```

`$attributeIds` return attribute codes like *street* if I select Street Address, *gender* if I select Gender and so on. Now what condition should be put in order to know whether a given attribute is customer or address attribute.

```
// Prepare Collection addition to store custom fields
foreach ($this->custom_columns as $col) 
{
   //Some Condition if its a Customer attribute
   collection->addAttributeToSelect($col);  
   //else some condition if its a Customer address attribute
   $collection->joinAttribute($col, "customer_address/$col", 'default_billing', null, 'left');
 }
 $this->setCollection($collection);
 return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

I just want to know what those *conditions* would be. Hope this is a little clearer

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're asking. Please try to make it clear what your problem is and post the code you've already tried, as well as any error messages you've received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [magic](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) `has*()` calls with each class extending `Varien_Object` to check whether a given property does, or does not exist.

Additionally, `Varien_Object` offers a non-magic `hasData('property_name')` method.

The `hasData()` method basically does the same thing, just indirectly - i.e. by passing the property name as argument to the method, instead of using it as camel-cased part of the methods name.

`Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` and `Mage_Customer_Model_Address` actually do extend `Varien_Object`, so you could call `hasData('street')` on an object instance to check for the existence of such property and use the result for your `if/else` scenario.

You could also magically call `hasStreet()`, but in your case the `hasData()` variant will definitely serve better (as you're looping thru an array with variable property names).

Note that `hasData()` can only help you distinguish *unique* property names. Of course you cannot use `hasData()` to distinguish properties of the same name existing in both classes (e.g. `'entity_id'`).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. That has helped me understand things better. So I can use something like *if(Mage::getModel('customer/entity_attribute_collection)->hasData($col)){do something...}else{something else...}*